# Auto complete in ComboBox windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I have auto complete functionality in combo box ,it works properly but there is little issue ,I made the suggestion list appear for the text length more than 3 chars ,but the list appears after the length of 4 char (when user enters the fifth char of the text) which means when the code executed in the first time the list doesn't  appear here is the code in `Text_Changed` Event

```
 Private Sub TxtItem_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtItem.TextChanged


    If Trim(TxtItem.Text) <> "" And Trim(TxtItem.Text).Length > 3 Then
        'Autocomplete
        Dim Bl As New ItemBL
        Dim suggestions = Bl.DisplayLikeNameList(Trim(TxtItem.Text))
        Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        MySource.AddRange(suggestions.ToArray)

        With TxtItem
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            .AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
        End With
        TxtItem.Select(TxtItem.Text.Length, 0)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        TxtItem.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
    End If

End Sub
```

Note : This issue causes the application exit (sometimes) on Windows XP, but Doesn't affect on Windows 7

Comment: It causes the application to exit? *How?*

Comment: sometimes when user enters text more 3 chars the application exits ,does not show exception message or something ,simply exits

Comment: Don't change AutoCompleteMode in an event handler, that has many side-effects.  Just make sure the source is empty if you don't want to display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer  was found in this post:  [Dynamically changing Textbox's AutoComplete List causes AccessViolationException, any advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779557/dynamically-changing-textboxs-autocomplete-list-causes-accessviolationexception)

So I had to make global list of suggestions and initialize the  `AutoComplete` property in the Form `load` event and it worked good .